Making a Passive Sentence from "Someone break the window."
 I have a situation: Someone break the window. How can be make this passive sentence?
They could have broken the window


Your title makes no sense at all. Present tense: Someone breaks the window. The window is broken by someone. Past tense: Someone has broken the window. The window has been broken by someone.

(This question has a more descriptive title now)

The homework is not a bad exercise, except that the sentence is messier in the passive.

"someone break the window" is grammatical only if it's an imperative, and I don't think that's what you want. to get the clearest answer, please edit to tell more about the meaning you're starting with and the meaning you want.

@FriendlyRacoon IMO your edit went a bit too far. The original title made no sense; you edited to replace it with text from the body of the question. This makes a reasonable guess at the OP's intent, but it might be the wrong guess. I would say a better approach to questions that are too unclear to answer is to vote to close and ask the OP to edit.

Thank your comment

I think OP wants the sentence in the text "could have broken" to be made passive.

Your question: “How can be make this passive sentence?” is poor English; it is ungrammatical. What is the subject in the question? In a positive sentence we might write: It can be made, the question form would be:  Can it be made?  A grammatical version of your question is: How can it be made into a passive sentence?* but it is not very idiomatic.  As your English is arguably weak, how will you know which is the best answer?

Which sentence do want to passivise? The one in the title or the one in the question body? Is the sentence highlighted in grey, your attempt to answer? I am sorry but I am voting to close the question.

OP's query:

Change to passive voice
"They could have broken the window".

In active voice the subject "they" performs the action of breaking the window.
In the passive voice, the subject receives the action,
If we convert the sentence to passive voice, it would become:
"The window could have been broken by them."
Active to Passive voice explanation:.
When converting active to passive voice, several changes occur:
Active Voice:
Subject (they) + Verb (broken) + Object (the window)
Passive Voice:
Object (the window) + Auxiliary Verb (could have) + Passive Verb (been broken) + by + Agent (them)

Verb changes:

Active verb (e.g., "broken") becomes passive verb ("been broken")
Auxiliary verb ("could have") remains the same.
(In the given sentence, the verb is already in past participle form. We have to add "be" verb = been).


Pronoun changes:

Subject pronoun ("they") becomes agent pronoun ("by them")


Word order changes:

Object ("the window") becomes the new subject
Subject ("they") becomes the agent (after "by")


Preposition addition:

"By" is added to introduce the agent ("by them")



These changes help rephrase the sentence to emphasize the receiver (object) instead of the doer (subject).

Oh thanks. I still think it is by they, which is false. That result's by them.

@ThanhDevS I have edited my answer to explain the steps of converting active voice to passive voice. We have to change the pronoun too. He = him, she = her, I= me, they= them.

In English, Active and Passive voice are mostly about which order words are in. Since English allows a lot of flexibility in word order, there are many different ways to say or write the same thing without changing the meaning. However, the order that you choose for the words in a sentence changes the tone (sometimes called the "voice").
In most cases, active voice sentences use Subject-Verb-Object order, while passive voice sentences use Object-Verb-Subject order.
A Subject is the main noun in a sentence. The person, place, or thing that is doing, saying, or being something. In this example, your subject is someone because that person is doing something.
A Verb is the action. In your example, your main verb is to break.
An Object is the noun that something is being done too. Not every sentence has an object, but this one does. In this example, your object is The window because it was the thing that was broken.
So, you have the Active Voice sentence:

Someone breaks the window.

In this sentence, you have Subject (someone) - Verb (to break) - Object (the window) in that order. To make it Passive, we need to flip the Object and the Subject placement, and to do that we will need a preposition and the verb tense will change slightly.
Passive Example

The window is broken by someone.

Here we need to add the preposition by to indicate that someone is still the subject, not an object. We also change the verb tense of to break from simple present to passive present.
(If we didn't make these changes, we would say "The window breaks someone" which would mean that a person is being injured by the actions of a window - this doesn't make any sense, since a window is a thing and can't do actions.)
Break vs Breaks
In your original example, you should say "Someone breaks the window." with an s on the end of breaks. This is because someone is a singular noun - they are only one person, and the verb needs to be conjugated to agree with that. Singular nouns get verbs with an S, while plural nouns get verbs with no S (mostly, as like all things in English, there are some exceptions).

". . . passive voice sentences use Object-Verb-Subject order." No. You are confusing semantic categories with grammatical categories.


The window was broken (by X)

I believe this would be the passive form of the sentence. Fluent English speakers would definitely understand it, but I don't think that most of us would consider this to be natural speech.

Yes that's right. The window was broken by them.

@ThanhDevS If we look at the original sentence in your question: “They could have broken the window” the solution by Weiwen “The window was broken [by X]” is inaccurate because it changes the meaning .
